# How to print a part of my page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to print only certain part of my page. My sample code follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <title>Insert title here</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            Blah... blah... 
        </div>
        <div class="printable">
           contents goes here...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to print the contents of `<div class="printable"></div>`. Is it possible to do this using jQuery? Should I write this solution, or is there a plugin that would help solve this problem?

Comment: I've never used it, but Google finds this: http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Answer (score 4):

### Add to HTML head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

### print.css

```
body * { display: none; }
.printable { display: block; }
```

### Javascript

```
window.print();
```

Answer (score 2):

i haven't get any good solution from stackoverflow so i am posting answer myself..

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
     printDivCSS = new String ('<link href="myprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">')
function printDiv(divId) {
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML=printDivCSS + document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus()
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print()
}
</head>
<body>
   <div class="body">
   Bla h......... blah... 
</div>
<div class="printable">
   contents goes here.........
</div>
<b></b> <a href=javascript:printDiv('printable')>Print This Div</a><br>
```

refer: [How do I print part of a rendered HTML page in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript)

Comment: there was that answer from 2009 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript#answer-1072151