# How can I print the contents of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the contents of a link get printed by jQuery. What do i do?

Following is my code:
**[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/9zLGZ/)**

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print</a> 
​
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#tools').prepend('<li class="print"><a href="#print">Click me to print</a></li>');
    $('ul#tools li.print a').click(function() {
        window.open('www.google.com');
        window.print();
        return false;
    });
}); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

"Printing the contents of a link" sounds ambiguous. I guess what you are trying to do is to print another web page? It might work if you opened the page in a new frame and printed that, it seems to me that [this question might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440976/how-ti-print-the-part-of-web-page-using-jquery).

Comment: No, i want get printed of full contents in a url. no only part of same web page

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call `print()` on the window you are opening, not the one the original code is running in.

```
var foo = window.open(bar, 'bar');
foo.print();
```

(You might run into timing issues if the window hasn't had time to load the document).

However, in you example you appear to be trying to open a third party page (although you forgot the `http://`). The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will prevent you accessing the print method of the remote document.

Comment: Can it be used in my code? Please give an example here:http://jsfiddle.net/9zLGZ/

Comment: Sadly you can not use any functions/methods of a cross-origin frame. You are opening a different domain and javascript does not allow javascript from domain A to run in domain B. `$(window.open('http://www.google.com')).ready(function(){this.print();});` will cause a cross-domain error. (also, that piece of code is what you want to use)