# Print a div content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I want to print the content of a div using jQuery. This question is already asked in SO, but I can't find the correct (working) answer.

This is is my HTML:

```
<div id='printarea'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
    <input type='button' id='btn' value='Print'>
</div>
<p>Do not print.</p>
```

Here I want to print the content of the div `printarea`.

I tried this:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#printarea").print();
});
```

But it gives a console error when the button is clicked:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).print is not a function

But when I am trying to print the entire page using

```
window.print();
```

it is working. But I only want to print the content of a particular div. I saw the answer `$("#printarea").print();` in many places , but this is not working.

Comment: You could setup a stylesheet with `media="print"` on it that hides all non-relevant content.

Comment: You're looking for a CSS solution here actually, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440976/how-to-print-a-part-of-my-page-using-jquery) is an easy setup for your purpose - it hides all the page elements except the ones with the class `.printable`

Comment: Using the JavaScript tag might be a good idea if you want to attract good answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290244/suggested-edits-do-questions-need-both-javascript-and-jquery-tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print the contents of a DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Some jQuery research has failed, so I moved to JavaScript (thanks for your suggestion [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2200659/anders)).

And it is working well...

**HTML**

```
<div id='DivIdToPrint'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
</div>
<p>Do not print.</p>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv();'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function printDiv() 
{

  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');

  var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

  newWin.document.open();

  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

  newWin.document.close();

  setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);

}
```

Comment: You will lost CSS/JS/Fonts

Comment: You should not use this because after using this you will lost your JS. like $(".class").click() and $(".class").change and other events.

Comment: also sometimes server timeout without showing print window.

Comment: This did not answer the question, you provided an alternative solution.

Comment: not a bad idea, instead you should use "onload="window.print();window.close();" which guarantees closing after printing/cancelling. because the timer isn't working when you take longer to react to the print page.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Not come css and fonts

Comment: @Deepu Sasidharan:sir can you tell me why i got window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=768px,width=1024px') return null

Answer (score 46):

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

```
$("#myID").printThis();
```

Great jQuery plugin to do exactly what you're after

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).printThis is not a function

Comment: @AbdelrahmanFarag check if you are including JQuery properly in your webpage.

   You can try the CDN option specified here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Great answer. It is working well as I expected. thanks

Comment: doesn't work on RTL Websites. It changed `font-family` ,`font-weight` and make all the text LTR that disorganize all the content.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do this without an extra plugin (like [printThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis)), I think this should work. The idea is to have a special div that will be printed, while everything else is hidden using CSS. This is easier to do if the div is a direct child of the body tag, so you will have to move whatever you want to print to a div like that. S So begin with creating a div with id `print-me` as a direct child to your body tag. Then use this code to print the div:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    //Copy the element you want to print to the print-me div.
    $("#printarea").clone().appendTo("#print-me");
    //Apply some styles to hide everything else while printing.
    $("body").addClass("printing");
    //Print the window.
    window.print();
    //Restore the styles.
    $("body").removeClass("printing");
    //Clear up the div.
    $("#print-me").empty();
});
```

The styles you need are these:

```css
@media print {
    /* Hide everything in the body when printing... */
    body.printing * { display: none; }
    /* ...except our special div. */
    body.printing #print-me { display: block; }
}

@media screen {
    /* Hide the special layer from the screen. */
    #print-me { display: none; }
}
```

The reason why we should only apply the `@print` styles when the `printing` class is present is that the page should be printed as normally if the user prints the page by selecting `File -> Print`.

Answer (score 10):

None of the solutions above work perfectly.They either loses CSS or have to include/edit external CSS file. I found a perfect solution that will not lose your CSS nor you have to edit/add external CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id='printarea'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
    <input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printFunc();'>
</div>
<p>Do not print.</p
```

Javascript:

```
function printFunc() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding;0.5em;' +
        '}' +
        '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'>Print Page</h3>");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    }
```

Comment: this is also not working with you css, here he give only table css so you can only get table (basic) now the all css elements.

Comment: yeah this lost all the styling

Answer (score 9):

Without using any plugin you can opt this logic.

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    //Hide all other elements other than printarea.
    $("#printarea").show();
    window.print();
});
```

Comment: Prints everything in the page on Mozila firefox

Comment: Prints everything in the page on Chrome v.72, too.

Comment: Have a div with the class ```.container```, and I have certain elements outside of that div like a search bar and a button, that I do not want to show on the print page. When I select ```$(".container").show()``` it still prints everything...

Answer (score 8):

I update this function

now you can print any tag or any part of the page with its full style 

must include jquery.js file

**HTML**

```
<div id='DivIdToPrint'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
</div>
<p>Do not print.</p>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printtag("DivIdToPrint");' >
```

**JavaScript**

```
        function printtag(tagid) {
            var hashid = "#"+ tagid;
            var tagname =  $(hashid).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() ;
            var attributes = ""; 
            var attrs = document.getElementById(tagid).attributes;
              $.each(attrs,function(i,elem){
                attributes +=  " "+  elem.name+" ='"+elem.value+"' " ;
              })
            var divToPrint= $(hashid).html() ;
            var head = "<html><head>"+ $("head").html() + "</head>" ;
            var allcontent = head + "<body  onload='window.print()' >"+ "<" + tagname + attributes + ">" +  divToPrint + "</" + tagname + ">" +  "</body></html>"  ;
            var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
            newWin.document.open();
            newWin.document.write(allcontent);
            newWin.document.close();
           // setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
        }
```

Comment: this should be the marked as the answer.  i tried all the other stuff and none of it worked.  they should give you a medal for this answer :)

Comment: @Jonathan Alfaro very thanks

Answer (score 8):

Below code from codepen worked for me as I wanted,

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

Here is a link [codepen](https://codepen.io/JefMari/pen/jqPJdV)

Comment: does not work in IE. For IE:        var printContent = document.getElementById("PrintContent");
        var windowUrl = 'Job Receipt';
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();

Answer (score 5):

use this library : [Print.JS](http://printjs.crabbly.com/)

with  this library you can print both HTML and PDF.

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="printJS-form">
    ...
 </form>

 <button type="button" onclick="printJS('printJS-form', 'html')">
    Print Form
 </button>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div id='printarea'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p> 
</div>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onlick="printDiv()">
<p>Do not print.</p>

function printDiv(){
        var printContents = document.getElementById("printarea").innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

This Above function should be load on same page.

Answer (score 5):

First include the header

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.print/1.6.0/jQuery.print.js"></script>
```

As you are using a print function with a selector which is a part of print.js so you need to call them before you use it...

```
Else 
    window.print()
```

will do it

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#printarea").print();
});
```

or

```
$("#btn").on('click',function () {
    $("#printarea").print();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code uses no library. works fine.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="printDoc">
<p> Print Me ! </p>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv("printDoc");' >
```

JavaScript CODE

```
<script>
        function printDiv(printDoc){
            var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
            var printcontent = document.getElementById(printDoc).innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the non-plugin approaches here, but all caused blank pages to print after the content, or had other problems.  Here's my solution:

Html:

```
<body>
<div id="page-content">        
    <div id="printme">Content To Print</div>
    <div>Don't print this.</div>
</div>
<div id="hidden-print-div"></div>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#hidden-print-div").html($("#printme").html());
    });
```

Css:

```
    #hidden-print-div {
        display: none;
    }

    @media print {
        #hidden-print-div {
            display: block;
        }

        #page-content {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at this
[Plugin](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

Makes your code as easy as -> `$('SelectorToPrint').printElement();`

Answer (score 1):

[Print only selected element on codepen](http://codepen.io/DenisDov/pen/yMEXGV)

HTML:

```
<div class="print">
 <p>Print 1</p>
 <a href="#" class="js-print-link">Click Me To Print</a>
</div>

<div class="print">
 <p>Print 2</p>
 <a href="#" class="js-print-link">Click Me To Print</a>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.js-print-link').on('click', function() {
  var printBlock = $(this).parents('.print').siblings('.print');
  printBlock.hide();
  window.print();
  printBlock.show();
});
```

Comment: how do i changed this to landscape ?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS CODE**

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 450px;}
    table, th, td {border: 1px solid #000000;}
    @media print {
        .print-btn{
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>      
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>      
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>        
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>        
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adam</td>
            <td>Johnson</td>        
            <td>67</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="print-btn" onclick="window.print()">Print me</button>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]