# how can I print this voucher to A4 size paper?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

```
<script>
function myFunction() {


window.print();
}
</script>
<form >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But I need to print Just My table Tr only

Answer (score 0):

Picked the code from here [Print a div content using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732739/print-a-div-content-using-jquery)

```
function myFunction() 
{

  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('IdOfDivTobePrinted');

  var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

  newWin.document.open();

  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

  newWin.document.close();

  setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);

}
```