# jQuery printelement function not working in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using printelement jQuery. Searching resource in stackoverflow and many others find some solution but still not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/neon-theme.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/datatables/responsive/css/datatables.responsive.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Print Blank page.

Comment: Title is misleading.

You are not using jquery you are using plain javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your css linking problem, Please try it :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
}
function Popup(data)
{
    var myWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
    myWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    myWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I will try but something css missing.

Comment: It's need to internal css. try it i hope problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this answer from a similar thread

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33735423/3514785

The code looks something like this:

```
var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');
var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
```

Comment: Then I suspect something else is an issue. It works for me. What do you get?

Comment: previously I used the html print whenever user prints the data it is generating webpartextension="full" with head tags at some point it throwing error (it is not printing )newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

Answer (score 0):

Thats right. Use jquery html like so `$('#divelement').html(yourehtmlcode)`.

Comment: This will change the element. How is this helping with the question?

Comment: Oh i thought that was the question xD

Comment: It's okay. Read the question properly next time. I'd suggest you delete this answer before someone down votes you :)

Comment: Not helping the question.