# Printing gantt chart into pdf using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am having a gantt chart in my web page which is generated by javascript. I am having a button in that page named "Print as PDF" to get the pdf version of that gantt chart.

I am using wkhtmltopdf for generating the pdf page. How this can be made with wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: use `window.print();` JavaScript function in your code.
[Click here for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732867/3453169).

Answer (score 0):

You may use this library which includes wkhtmltopdf executables:
https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64