# How can print image (external URL) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I am using following code but it is not working. It

```
        url = "http:www.google.com/img/1.jpg"
        popup = window.open();
        popup.document.write(url);                        
        popup.print();
```

Any other approach?

Comment: Note that you are writing the url, not a tag `<img>`

Comment: Please load your image inside img tag with some parent div and then print the div

Answer (score 0):

Load your image inside img tag with some parent div and then print the div. The example is as follows:

More on print a div can be found here [Print a div content using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732739/print-a-div-content-using-jquery)

```js
var url = "https://mediaserver.goepson.com/ImConvServlet/imconv/9b7d08e02138222989a0f61975f424e1bf046300/original?use=productpictures&assetDescr=google-cloud-print_690x460"
$('#prinatabbleDiv').append("<img src='" + url + "' onload='iamready()'>");

function iamready() {
  console.log('ready to print');
  //$("#prinatabbleDiv").print();
  printDiv("prinatabbleDiv")
}

function printDiv(id) {

  var divToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
  var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
  newWin.document.open();
  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
  newWin.document.close();
  setTimeout(function() {
    newWin.close();
  }, 10);

}
```

```css
#prinatabbleDive {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='prinatabbleDiv'></div>
```

Comment: In print dialog it is showing "[object HTMLDivElement]" instead of image

Comment: have updated the code as per your requirement please upvote and accept if satisfies the need!

Comment: Checking your code

Comment: OK, Please do let me know if any problem occurs! Please upvote and accept if satisfies.