# How to print a div that has a canvas using JavaScript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I wanted to print a specific div that has a canvas consisting of a chart. I had written a script to print the specific div in my HTML body tag but it returns everything except the graph.
This is what I want:
[image: What I Want]

This is what I get:
[image: What I get]

How can I achieve the results shown in image 1? Thanks in advance.

This is my code for the script:

```
<script>
    //Print specific div
    function printFunc() {
        var tagname = $('#div-report').prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
        var attributes = "";
        var attrs = document.getElementById("div-report").attributes;
        $.each(attrs, function(i, elem) {
            attributes += " " + elem.name + " ='" + elem.value + "' ";
        })
        var divToPrint = $('#div-report').html();
        var head = "<html><head>" + $("head").html() + "</head>";
        var allcontent = head + "<body  onload='window.print()' >" + "<" + tagname + attributes + ">" + divToPrint + "</" + tagname + ">" + "</body></html>";
        var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
        newWin.document.open();
        newWin.document.write(allcontent);
        newWin.document.close();
    };
</script>
```

This is my code for the front-end HTML(in case you need it):

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
<div class="container p-2 pb-0 mt-5 pt-3" id="admin-dashboard">
    <h2 class="pt-3 pb-5 display-6">Report Summary</h2>
    <div class="row g-2 mb-5  justify-content-md-end">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="button" onclick="printFunc()" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .5rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: 1rem; --bs-btn-font-size: .75rem;">Print</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container pb-0" id="div-report">
    <div ALIGN=CENTER>
        <b>
            <h6>Report Summary Generated on DD/MM/YYYY
        </b>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div ALIGN=CENTER>
        <p>
            Demo
        </p>
    </div>
    <a class=" nav nav-item text-decoration-none text-muted" href="cstaff-report-generation.php">
        <i class="bi bi-arrow-left-square me-2"></i>Go back</a>
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3 py-3">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-info">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M8 10a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z" />
                            <path d="M0 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4zm3 0a2 2 0 0 1-2 2v4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2H3z" />
                        </svg>
                        Total Sales Revenue
                    </h6>
                    <p class="card-text my-2">
                        Demo
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-info">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-receipt" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M1.92.506a.5.5 0 0 1 .434.14L3 1.293l.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L5 1.293l.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L7 1.293l.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L9 1.293l.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .801.13l.5 1A.5.5 0 0 1 15 2v12a.5.5 0 0 1-.053.224l-.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.8.13L13 14.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 14.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 14.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L7 14.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L5 14.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L3 14.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.801-.13l-.5-1A.5.5 0 0 1 1 14V2a.5.5 0 0 1 .053-.224l.5-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .367-.27zm.217 1.338L2 2.118v11.764l.137.274.51-.51a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l.646.647.646-.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.646.646-.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.646.646-.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.646.646-.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.646.646-.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.509.509.137-.274V2.118l-.137-.274-.51.51a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L12 1.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L10 1.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L8 1.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L6 1.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L4 1.707l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.509-.51z" />
                            <path d="M3 4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h6a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h6a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h6a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm8-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
                        </svg>
                        Total Number of Order Placed
                    </h6>
                    <p class="card-text my-2">
                      Demo
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-info">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M6 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H1s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C9.516 10.68 8.289 10 6 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.854 5.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L12.5 7.793l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
                        </svg>
                        Total Number of Customer Visited
                    </h6>
                    <p class="card-text my-2">
                       Demo
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-info">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-diagram-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7.5 2h1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10 3.5v1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 8.5 6v1H11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8h-5v.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-1A.5.5 0 0 1 5 7h2.5V6A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6 4.5v-1zM8.5 5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1zM3 11.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.5 10h1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 11.5v1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 14h-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 12.5v-1zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1zm4.5.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5-1.5h1a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1.5v1a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 12.5v-1zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1z" />
                        </svg>
                        Best-Selling Menu Item
                    </h6>
                    <p class="card-text my-2">
                       Demo
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card border-info">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-hourglass-split" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M2.5 15a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1h1v-1a4.5 4.5 0 0 1 2.557-4.06c.29-.139.443-.377.443-.59v-.7c0-.213-.154-.451-.443-.59A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 3.5 3V2h-1a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-1v1a4.5 4.5 0 0 1-2.557 4.06c-.29.139-.443.377-.443.59v.7c0 .213.154.451.443.59A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 12.5 13v1h1a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11zm2-13v1c0 .537.12 1.045.337 1.5h6.326c.216-.455.337-.963.337-1.5V2h-7zm3 6.35c0 .701-.478 1.236-1.011 1.492A3.5 3.5 0 0 0 4.5 13s.866-1.299 3-1.48V8.35zm1 0v3.17c2.134.181 3 1.48 3 1.48a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-1.989-3.158C8.978 9.586 8.5 9.052 8.5 8.351z" />
                        </svg>
                        Peak Hour
                    </h6>
                    <p class="card-text my-2">
                       Demo
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <h4 class="border-top fw-light pt-3 mt-2">Menu Performance</h4>
    <div class="container p-2 pb-0 mt-2 mb-5 pt-3" style="text-align: center;">
        <canvas id="mpChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Teemu I followed the code provided in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732739/print-a-div-content-using-jquery

Comment: Make your life easier, and take a look at [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).