# How to Print the Data that has been Populated by MYSQL in PHP or HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

The code below is my way on how to print my data in Table.

```
<style media="screen">
  .noPrint{ display: block; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>

<style media="print">
  .noPrint{ display: none; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>
```

Here is my code of printing the data from the table

```
  <div style = "border:1px solid; height:360px; width:1180px; left: 180px; position: absolute; top: 95px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <div class= "yesPrint">
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("dbreport",$con);
    $sql = "select * from tblreport";
    $mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    echo "<table border=1 id='tbody'>
    <tr>
    <th>Crime Name</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Detail</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Crime Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Detail'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";



    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_Close($con);
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

To initiate the command

```
<input TYPE="button" value = "Print Report" onClick="window.print()">
```

Further Explanation: My code here is to print the data from my table and the table has been populated from my database. Data Transfer to Table then Print but what happens is the whole website has been print. It seems that my code Capture the site as Image and this what it print.

What I want to do is print what only on the table, how can achieve it? TY

Comment: I don't get what you are asking, you are looping through the RESULTS of a query, which will display what's in the table??????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print specific part of webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997123/print-specific-part-of-webpage)

Comment: The easiest way is to use `@media print` in your CSS to define how you want the printed document to look (and hide parts your *don't* want)

Comment: I just want to print the data on my table. and my table is filled with data from my database

Comment: @Caddaile You post a possible duplicate along with an answer; that's not very fair.

Comment: My apologies, I realized I can flag it after I posted, and forgot to delete - done by now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

you r using **mysql_Close($con);** but in real **mysql_close($con);**

```
<div style = "border:1px solid; height:360px; width:1180px; left: 180px; position: absolute; top: 95px; overflow-x: auto;">
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
<div class= "yesPrint">
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbreport",$con);
$sql = "select * from tblreport";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table border=1 id='tbody'>
<tr>
<th>Crime Name</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Detail</th>
</tr>";

while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Crime Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['Detail'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He want to print the table, the specific elements of the page only, he go not problems with the query.

Comment: Yes Sir thats what i want, I have no problem with my PHP command

Answer (score 0):

With the below javascript function, you can print any element by just placing the element in the parentheses.

```
<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('.yesPrint')" />
```

Here is the entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>

<div style = "border:1px solid; height:360px; width:1180px; left: 180px; position: absolute; top: 95px; overflow-x: auto;" class="noPrint">
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
        <div class= "yesPrint">
            <?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("dbreport",$con);
            $sql = "select * from tblreport";
            $mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            ?>
            <table border=1 id='tbody'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Crime Name</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Detail</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $record['Crime Name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $record['Time'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $record['Date'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $record['Address'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $record['Detail'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </table>
            <?php mysql_close($con); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('.yesPrint')" />
```