# Print a div with data from ajax or jquery.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, printing

I have a div:

```
<div id="contract"></div>
```

that gets populated by JQuery using innerHTML with strings from client side javascript and data (HTML) got from my server:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {       
    document.getElementById('contract').innerHTML = 'foobar';    
    var profile = $('#profile').val();
    var query = {
        'profile': profile
    };
    $.get('/foo/profileViewer', query, function (data) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);            
        document.getElementById('contract').innerHTML += result ;  //$('#contract').html(result); doesn't work either         
    })
});
```

I want to print just the `contract` `div`.

I tried the JQuery answers suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12997207/1550852) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072151/1550852) and all point to answers where `div` **already** contains the text in HTML to start with and not something which is obtained from a server. Weirdly, if I remove the `$.get` and implement one of the answers provided, `"foobar"` **does** get printed. If I do not remove the `$.get`, **nothing** gets printed. I tried using `$.ajax` instead of `$.get` but this does not resolve the issue. I tried using the CSS solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618980/1550852) but that messes up my data (HTML) coming from the server side as it already has CSS paged media embedded in it. Hence, I do not want to use the CSS solutions.

Could anyone please suggest me a good way to use JQuery to print a `div` when the `div` contains data obtained from the server side?

Comment: show us your code from `/foo/profileViewer`

Comment: what do you mean by print?

Comment: By print I mean actually making the browser pop up a print window that prints the part of the webpage I want

Answer (score 1):

Try using a hidden iframe:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();     
    $('#contract').empty();    
    var profile = $('#profile').val();
    var query = {
        profile: profile
    };
    $.get('/foo/profileViewer', query, function (data) {            
        $('body').append('<iframe id="printf" style="display:none;" name="printf"></iframe>');
        $('#printf').contents().find('body').append(data);
         window.frames["printf"].focus();
         window.frames["printf"].print();       
    })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/njezoem5/

Answer (score 0):

Go this way

```
$('#contract').text(JSON.stringify(data));
```

or

```
$('#contract').append(
    $('<pre>').text(
        JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ')
    )
)
```

Comment: I tried `$('#contract').html(result);` too before and it wasn't working for me. Hence,I shifted to `document.getElementById('contract').innerHTML += result ;`

Answer (score -1):

you can not print a tag directly .But this trick can help:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divID) {
        //Get the HTML of div
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        //Get the HTML of whole page
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
        document.body.innerHTML = 
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
          divElements + "</body>";

        //Print Page
        window.print();

        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;


    }
</script>
```

Comment: It screws up all the dynamic functionality of the page: buttons etc.