# print html page inside form element

Tags: javascript

A web page has `<form>` which needs to be sent to the printer for printing. Keyboard <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will print the whole page which is not what I want.

I wired up the event to a button on the footer but not sure how to send only the `form` content to the printer. Any idea how?

`$('form').get(0).innerHTML`

Comment: write a print css file and hide the stuff you don't want to show

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997123/print-specific-part-of-webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that element from page like a block and use Javascript to print it

```
<div class="print" onclick="PrintElem('#idFromPage')">
```

And Js code to print the block you need:

```
    function PrintElem(elem) {
    Popup($("body").html(), elem);
}

function Popup(data, elem) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Page to Print', 'height=600,width=800');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Document</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<style> body * { visibility: hidden;  } .mobile-view {displa:none;} body, html { background:#fff !important;}   #' + elem + ', #' + elem + ' * {visibility: visible; } </style>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    $(mywindow).on('load', function () {
        mywindow.print();
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using `media queries`. It'll work in IE9 and above, Chrome, FF, etc. For IE8, you can use polyfills.

Now all you've to do is hide the elements when printing. Write something like this in your css

```
@media print {
    #element-to-hide {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This will completely hide the unwanted elements while printing.

Comment: event thought this works but it leaves blank space where the elemnt-to-hide was thus the form content which was expected to use one page, it is still taking 2 pages in the printer, where as if it is in it's own page, it will print one page only.

Comment: You can readjust the width, height, etc. of visible elements as well. That way you'll have no white space while printing