# How to print a part of a webpage, including what was selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print a specific part of a webpage. But whenever I try to print it, it doesn't show the radio button I have selected, what's in a text box or what I have selected from the drop down menu. Can you please tell me how can I achieve this in the following code

```
<html>
    <head>       
    <script>
        printDivCSS = new String ('<link href="myprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">')
        function printDiv(divId) {
            window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML=printDivCSS + document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Some information that doesn't need to be printed</p>

        <div id="div1">This is the Part that need to be printed<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
        <br>
        <select>
        <option value="empty"> </option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <p>Print out need to show the gender and the car brand I have selected</p>
        </div>        
        <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
        <b>Click here to Print:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('div1')">Print</a><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Please show me with an example code if possible

Comment: Did you define styles for print only? Using the @print media query

Comment: what happens if an option is preselected on pageload, does it print selected then?

Comment: Hi. the HTML doe's not contain the user select. you can use the same page to print. just close your print-css code with @media print {}

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and answers. But I can not use `@media print   {      .unwanted-div, button{      display:none;       }        }` If I use this, it will still print out menu buttons at the very top, logo and all the unwanted things of my WordPress site. Can you show me an example of how to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print specific part of webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997123/print-specific-part-of-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one if there is unwanted `div` just put `@media print` and `display:none;`. As you can see when you print `uwanted-div`and button is not showing.

```css
@media print
   {
      .unwanted-div, button{
      display:none;  
      }       
   }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="unwanted-div">
          Some information that doesn't need to be printed</p>
      </div>

        <div id="div1">This is the Part that need to be printed<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
        <br>
        <select>
        <option value="empty"> </option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <p>Print out need to show the gender and the car brand I have selected</p>
        </div>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But I can not use @media print { .unwanted-div, button{ display:none; } } If I use this, it will still print out menu buttons at the very top, logo and all the unwanted things of my WordPress site (Which I have no control to hide). Can you please update your answer to solve this.