# How to print data from the div

Tags: javascript, php, html, printing

I just creating a booking website, after all I need to print the booking data printout, i just use `window.print();` to print, but the whole page is printing, I need only the data from the div.

Comment: Would be useful to see the div you're talking about.. paste some code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print the contents of a DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print specific part of webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997123/print-specific-part-of-webpage)

Comment: But those have value is, but in my case value are from out source, (API)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in jquery.

```
$('#YourdivId').printElement();
```