# Print (on a printer) file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, printers

is there any way of printing a file on a printer in rails? 
Let's assume I have a

```
  def print_url
     "/system/tickets/#{print_url_dir}/print.png"
  end
```

and I want to call it with

```
  resource.print_url
```

I tried already

```
  <%= link_to 'Print', resource.print_url, :onclick => 'window.print();return false;'%>
```

But that just opened the printer dialog for the site I am on.

Sorry if it is a stupid question or I am missing something.

Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this from a webpage - it's more of a Javascript task rather than Ruby/Rails one. You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '_blank', 'left=0,top=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  WinPrint.document.write('<img src="<%= resource.print_url %>" />');
  WinPrint.document.close();
  WinPrint.focus();
  WinPrint.print();
  WinPrint.close();
</script>
```

It creates and open new window with content that contains only the image that would like to print, then print the page (which you already noticed that invokes the dialog) and the closes that new window. (I don't think there's a way to skip the dialog opening though).

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997123/print-specific-part-of-webpage) answer for more information and examples.