# How to print dropdown selection value in Print.js?

Tags: html

please could you assist with printing a dropdown selection value when using the Print.js Javascript Library, the original selection remains and it does not dynamically change when you get the print window...

https://codepen.io/markchavush/pen/WWrWda

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your page title here :)</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
   <form method="post" action="#" id="printJS-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="exampleEmailInput">Your email</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="test@mailbox.com" id="exampleEmailInput">
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="exampleRecipientInput">Reason for contacting</label>
      <select class="u-full-width" id="exampleRecipientInput">
        <option value="Option 1">Questions</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Admiration</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Can I get your number?</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="exampleMessage">Message</label>
  <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Hi Dave …" id="exampleMessage"></textarea>


</form>
      <button type="button" onclick="printJS({ printable: 'printJS-form', type: 'html', header: 'PrintJS - Form Element Selection', css: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton-framework/1.1.1/skeleton.min.css' })">
    Print Form with Header
 </button>
</div>
<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please go directly to the codepen and press the print button to see that the dropdown list value does not appear correctly in the printout...

Cheers

Mark

Comment: minimal reproducible example? cant help blind

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment and read [ask] and edit your question with [mcve] and explain in detail what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Apologies all, I will add a codepen link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, not with the Print.js library.

The problem you're facing is a known issue - there was [an issue](https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/186) created on their GitHub repo detailing this exact issue back in 2018. (*That issue was merged to [this open issue](https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/187) instead, since apparently it's the same problem*). The original GitHub issuer even created a JSFiddle demoing the same problem you show in your codepen.

My only recommendation would be to attempt to implement something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12997207/8026947), though I won't pretend it will be easy.