# How to adjust printer's color profile / options using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Currently my web page is full of various text colors but when I try to print the page then all text colors are displaying in black color only. So how can I make so page text displays in original colors (not black fonts & white background) when print / print preview it?

Another thing is that, using below code I am able to hide header, footer from web page during printing but how can I print only specific area of web page instead of entire web page? My page is designed using HTML, CSS, DIV and Bootstrap. So is it possible to do it using PHP or Javascript or CSS? Please help.

**CSS Code**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print 
{
    header, .footer, footer { display: none; }
    color-adjust: [economy | exact]; // I tried this for color profile but not working
}
@page 
{
    size:  auto;
    margin: 0mm;
}
html
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    margin: 0px;
}
body
{
    border: solid 1px black ;
    margin: 10mm 15mm 10mm 15mm; /* margin you want for the content */
}
</style>
```

**HTML & Javascript code**

```
<button onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-print"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Print&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
```

I tried this code in CSS for color option but not working.
`color-adjust: [economy | exact];`

**EDIT#1**

I have done following in my CSS and HTML to skip printing of specific data on web page. But not working.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print 
{ .noprint{display:none}; }
</style>

<div class="row padding-10 noprint">
    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
        This text should not be printed on printer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to print only a part, what I do is I add a class called `noprint` to everything that I don't want printed (or its parent if all children will be not printed). Then in the print media query, add `.noprint{display:none}` instead of the header,footer etc..

Comment: the choice to print black or colors is set from the printer by the user. There is nothing you can do about, but eventually a disclaimer and a recommandation to reset the printer setting if they want colors (bg is the same, the user decides).

Comment: You should check your printer.  I have a colour printer, but I often print things in "greyscale "- so any preview starts as that and I have to change it to "colour"

Comment: @ATD, I checked that settings and it's not `greyscale`... I even tried to print this page and fonts are displaying in original colors during print preview / print.

Comment: @imvain2, I have updated my question and added code as per your suggestions but not working. Please have a look at my updated info and advise.

Comment: You can always try the hated `!important`: `.noprint{display:none !important};`

Comment: @imvain2, I already tried but no luck yet

Comment: the semi-colon was in the wrong place - try this { .noprint{display:none;} }

Comment: @John, still not working

Comment: Finally, this answer helped me to print specific part of web page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48215828/7688114