# How to print dynamically-created HTML via c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have HTML generated on a form. If you click a button, the HTML is generated and is currently placed in a ASP Textbox with just the text

```
<!doctype html><html>....</html>
```

and I want to automatically print this HTML (including the styling that is only for the generated body).

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't find anything /to/ try. Whenever I search, nothing seems to be what I want. Everyone suggests writing the stuff to a .html file then printing that, but I'm not able to do that.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part of "writing the stuff to a .html file and printing that" are you getting stuck on?

Comment: The fact that I'm at work and the bossman says to do it otherwise.

Comment: So, are you saying you want a Rich Text style text box to contain formatting, colours etc and then be able to print that? Similar to the code snippets you get on here?

Comment: I've generated some plain-Jane HTML. It's being stored in an ASP.NET TextBox for now. I want to create a new tab that prints the contents of that textbox (TextBox1.Text) which is "<!doctype>..."

Comment: You want to display the rendered HTML? Or just the HTML text (like code blocks in SO)? Also, textbox isn't ideal to allow for HTML input.

Comment: As @MikeSmithDev states you need to be clear by what you want. Do you want to DISPLAY on the screen or PRINT to a printer?

Comment: I want to print to a printer. Specifically, I want the standard print dialogue to pop up to the user.

Also, I want the /rendered/ HTML to be printed, not the HTML text.

Comment: I use [this](http://www.irt.org/script/1403.htm) link very helpful. Focus on the last answer/example.

Answer (score 1):

To print your code you need to do several things

1. Tell the browser what to print, [here's a few ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only), or create a new window with only the stuff to print.
2. Find a way to show the plain code, like using `<pre>` tags or the mentioned CodeMirror
3. Launch the print dialog, a simple javascript basically something like `window.print()`

There will be no *automatic* printing (unless you target IE with some black magic) as that would be insane to allow on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) is the one you might want to try. It displays and formats HTML text with colors.

http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trigger the print request using Javascript, but you can set this off using C# (look at the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) for usage).

The `window.print()` function is what you need.

You will presumably want to restrict what you print, [take a look at this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript) for ideas.