# print() an element based on its id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to print only a table from a webpage whose id is `"test1"`

```
function printPage() { 
  $var = document.getElementById('test1');
  print($var); 
}
```

In print preview, the whole document is appearing and not the table. Most likely the entire page will be printed while all I want is my table to be printed.

Comment: that's not going to work. you need to define a `@media=print` stylesheet which hides everything except what you want to print. or clone that node into an iframe and then call that iframe's print().

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to print part of rendered html page in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript)

Comment: @Marc B - that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work. you need to define a `@media=print` stylesheet which hides everything except what you want to print. or clone that node into an `<iframe>` and then call that iframe's `print()`.

Comment: Or they could use: `@media print { /* hide everything but your id here */ }` within their existing stylesheet if  it doesn't take up too much space.