# How to open new window in angularjs and option for print?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i combine this `$windows.open()` and `$windows.print()` so when user click on button to open new windows with some specific content and that have option for print?

EDIT: I figure out to use `$window.open().print()` to open window with print option but how to fill out with specific content

Answer (score 0):

You CAN NOT specify the content to print. The print function will print the current page.

However, you can use [css mediatype](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) as a workaround.

First, create a div containing all the content you want to print, use the css to make it disappear.

```
 #printDiv { display: none }
 <div id="printDiv"></div>
```

Then use the css mediatype to hide all other elements, display only what you want to print:

```
@media print {
  * { display: none}
  #printDiv {display: block}
}
```

Another solution is using an iframe as specified here: [How do I print part of a rendered HTML page in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript)

Comment: can i create partial view and then called partial view?

Comment: The print() method will print the entire page, so I think you can't.

Comment: I checked it again. Using an iframe maybe a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript

Comment: I mean to open in new window that partial view and then call print() method?

Comment: I changed my answer. You should load the html of the partial view into an iframe, then print that iframe only :D.