# Printing a picture attachment in a asp.net website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print an image that shows on a web page, but I cannot seem to print the image.

The following code is from [how to print part of rendered html page in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript/1072151#1072151), but this only prints a page with a title but no image

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print Test Page</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            printDivCSS = new String ('<link href="myprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">')
            function printDiv(divId) {
                window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML=printDivCSS + document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
                window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
                window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><b><center>This is a test page for printing</center></b><hr color=#00cc00 width=95%></h1>
        <b>Div 1:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('div1')">Print</a><br />
        <div id="div1">
            <img src="C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/descarga.jpg" id="imagehtml" class="img-responsive" alt="Visualización del original de la forma migratoria" />
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <b>Div 2:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('div2')">Print</a><br />
        <div id="div2">This is the div2's print output</div>
        <br /><br />
        <b>Div 3:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('div3')">Print</a><br />
        <div id="div3">This is the div3's print output</div>
        <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```