# Print HTML without opening in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

Without rendering the HTML first, just print the HTML without opening a new tab, is that possible? Below is my existing code that works printing in a new tab:

```
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $(data).html();

  $(w.document.body).html(html);
  w.print();
```

Comment: `window.open` will open a blank window. What is expected? is you want to print the innerHTML of body that before showing it to screen?

Comment: @RohitBatta for example in stackoverflow, there's a button when u click it will call some ajax, and the response is html, can print that piece of html without opening a new tab?

Comment: You can perhaps render it in a hidden section & print it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, you could print that html response. You could either assign that html response to any div and then print that section. You could check the link provided in above comment by @loxxy

Comment: You can render HTML somewhere in the same page and control what appears on screen and what is printed with [CSS @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) directives in your style sheet.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I don't want to render the html to the user, but directly print for them.

Comment: Yes, your question makes that clear. If you go the @media route for printing, the page would still have screen-borne content - yes? You would need `@media screen` for display to the user, and `@media print` to determine what gets printed. By defining *both* types of content, they will be mutually exclusive - the screen stuff will not print and the print stuff will not appear on the screen - geddit?

Comment: in chrome, you can `console.log(HTMLElement)` it will print all of the properties of an html element... Buuuut, I guess you are not asking that.

Comment: media screen is for css, I'm talking about the content (html)

Comment: Alicia, you need to do some gentle [background reading](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 0):

- remove window.open();
- example

Get Print Data

```
var printData = document.getElementById('printID').innerHTML;
```

Get the HTML of whole page

```
var originalData = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Add printData to html

```
document.body.innerHTML =
 "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
 printData + "</body>";
```

Print Page

```
window.print();
```

Restore orignal HTML

```
document.body.innerHTML = originalData;
```