# how to print QR Code with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print only QR code div instead of full page.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="qrcodeCanvas"></div> //Generating QR in this div

<a id="Html2Image" href="#qrcodeCanvas">Download</a>
<a id="mydiv" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="PrintDiv();" >Print</a>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcode.js"></script>


<script>
function PrintDiv()
{

}
</script>


<script>
var id  =   'Content';
$('#qrcodeCanvas').qrcode(id);

var canvas = $('#qrcodeCanvas canvas');
var img = $(canvas)[0].toDataURL("image/png");

$("#Html2Image").attr("download", "QR_Code.png").attr("href", img); //Downloading QR image
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "print" do you mean actual _printing_? If so use `window,print()` and hide everything except it using CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print part of a rendered HTML page in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-do-i-print-part-of-a-rendered-html-page-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

@ImmanuelNL's answer should work, but it will nuke *everything*. Event handlers, any references to elements in code, everything will be broken.

Instead, consider this nondestructive approach:

```
var tmp = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    printme = document.getElementById('printableArea').cloneNode(true);
while(document.body.firstChild) {
    // move elements into the temporary space
    tmp.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
}
// put the cloned printable thing back, and print
document.body.appendChild(printme);
window.print();

while(document.body.firstChild) {
    // empty the body again (remove the clone)
    document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
}
// re-add the temporary fragment back into the page, restoring initial state
document.body.appendChild(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came accros this sollution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="printableArea">
  <div id="qrcodeCanvas"></div>
</div>
<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

 window.print();

 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a qr!" />

</body>
</html>
```

Credits: asprin

Comment: @VkyArain it does print the QR code NOTICE <div id="qrcodeCanvas"></div> on line 5!